# Some websites display in html & text mode

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router

I use Windows 10 and for the last few days, I face a problem on some website few of them are moz.com, edx.org, coursera etc.

[image: An example image of issue that I am facing]

I face the similar problem on my laptop and desktop system which is connected by one Dlink router. I use wifi for laptop and wired connection from the wifi modem to the desktop.

I used mobile 4g internet to check the problematic website are working fine. Is it a router problem?

I did reset and reboot of router both did not help. Firewall checked it is normal.

Comment: It's indicative of a slow or 'incomplete' connection. Reboot all your network hardware for starters, then check firewall/antivirus settings.

Comment: What browser is this? Does it happen with an alternative browser? Could be that some page elements (such as CSS) are being blocked by something like an over-zealous ad blocker.

Comment: i cross check with all browser, and my two system too. It shows same issues.

Comment: As advised by Tetsujin, i reboot the router but it shows same issues again. should i reset the router?

Answer (score 7):

Coursera, like many websites, uses a different domain to load resources such as the CSS stylesheets, in their case a CDN from Amazon. For coursera.org, viewing the page source reveals:

```
<link href="https://d3njjcbhbojbot.cloudfront.net/webapps/builds/front-page/app.ad4352e12e75c33c5276.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

For moz.com:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2eeipcrcdle6.cloudfront.net/assets/dist/styles/moz-b259826f.min.css">
```

Maybe cloudfront.net is having problems in your region, or is blocked somewhere:

- Getting the resource directly (like [d3njjcbhbojbot.cloudfront.net/...c5276.css](https://d3njjcbhbojbot.cloudfront.net/webapps/builds/front-page/app.ad4352e12e75c33c5276.css)) might show an error message.
- Amazon's status page might help: https://status.aws.amazon.com/
- If the problem shows in different browsers, then somehow your modem/router, virus scanner or even your provider might be blocking those.
- If the direct link works, then some browser plugin that prohibits third-party content might be the culprit.
- If the direct link does not work, maybe the settings of your DNS servers (either on the computers and/or in the router) got compromised by some malware. In that case you might have noticed some weird advertisements as well. See, for example:

  - [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)
  - [Is my router infected? DNS settings affected](https://superuser.com/questions/1067109/is-my-router-infected-dns-settings-affected)
  - [Why are my router's DNS settings changing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1057962/why-are-my-routers-dns-settings-changing)

You might see some indicator in your browser's location bar (for some browsers, look at the right, not at the left) or developer tools (for IE hit F12 to open those).

Comment: I Check in all browser in my two system face similar issues. I reboot the router. Not yet do reset. should I ? or any other possibility to fix the issues.

Comment: Did you check the first two bullets?

Comment: i shows this error "This site can’t be reached". For second i mean the amazon. I am not really getting how to use it to diagnosis the issues

Comment: See the new 5th bullet.

Comment: I just noticed that https://www.edx.org/ is not using Amazon's CloudFront for their stylesheets. So this may not be about cloudfront.net being blocked. You might want to focus on edx.org, like check if https://www.edx.org/sites/default/files/css/css_xE-rWrJf-fncB6ztZfd2huxqgxu4WO-qwma6Xer30m4.css loads directly.

Comment: it loaded i could see all codes , i think there is no issues. any suggestion

Comment: Nope, if the direct link for the edx.org CSS works, but https://edx.org does not load properly on multiple machines and in different browsers, then I'm out of ideas and you'll need to dive into understanding the (F12) developer tools to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

For the Coursera issue- This is a problem with the local ISP provider(BSNL) in India. They appear to be blocking all outbound traffic to domains like ***.cloudfront.net**.

The page fails to load its css and hence gets displayed incorrectly. Ask them to stop blocking or switch to an alternate ISP- have verified that the page loads correctly on others.